# Retrieve a file information with fileID belonging to a particular user in "Spring"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a files list under different users. Now that I have to retrieve a file info of a particular user.

The url looks something like localhost:8081/somepath/{fileid}?userid=" "

Is it anyway possible to use sping jpa's findbyId? Please suggest me some way of doing it.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be a bit more precise with what you are trying to achieve and what you tried so far. Who specified that URL and where does JPA come into play? What ID are you using for the findbyid the fileid or the userid?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `File` entity with foreign key `userId`, you can create Spring Data repository with method `findByUserId()`. For example:

```
public interface FileRepositoryImpl extends PagingAndSortingRepository<File, Long> {

    Page<File> findAll(Pageable pageRequest);

    Page<File> findByUserId(String userId, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Just make sure you have getter and setter for `userId`.

You can find out more info in the [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)